# Trying to print mouse direction in 360 degrees

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

I am currently trying to implement a 360 degree direction listener of mouse inputs and print these to the terminal (long term is plotting these inputs). Looking to get advice on what libraries people are using and the best implementation you all have had with it.

I have been able to get mouse position through Pyautogui to out put position but not direction.

I have been able to implement cardinal directions with pynput.mouse but doing it in 360 degrees continues to be a problem.

Comment: What do you mean "mouse direction"? At any given moment in time, the mouse only has a position -- no direction. 

I suppose what you can do is infer some direction by taking the last two positions and taking the vector between them?

Comment: @Jabrove that was essentially what I was trying to do. I am lacking brainpower this afternoon. The suggested solution solved my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need two mouse positions to be able to get a direction.

If you have two mouse positions (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) then you can infer the direction with this function:

```
def get_angle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    # Calculate the angle of movement in radians
    angle_rad = math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
    
    # Convert the angle to degrees
    angle_deg = math.degrees(angle_rad)
    
    return angle_deg
```